# How to make Swagger show examples of objects returned from the API?

Tags: c#, .net, api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am creating a set of API's for the first time.  Here's one of the methods:

```
    // GET: api/Doors/0
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a list of all doors for a given organization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="organizationSys">The Organization ID for which all doors should be retreived.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [Route("{organizationSys:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys)
    {
        try
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters.Add("@OrganizationSys", organizationSys);
            List<Door> doors = Repository<Doors>.GetList("WHERE OrganizationSys = @OrganizationSys", parameters).ToList();
            if (doors == null || doors.Count() == 0)
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, RejectionMessage.NoItemsFound);

            return Ok(doors);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've set up a Unit Test to this endpoint, and it works perfectly.  However, I do have one question.

In Swagger, I'd like to show an example of the data object that will be returned.  The only return type on the method is `IHttpActionResult` so I'm not surprised it's not showing the data model in Swagger.  So, what do I need to change with this method so that the return object (in this case `List<Door>`) will be more visible?

Does Swashbuckle support this?

Thanks!

Comment: This Q looks a lot like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49028001/html-example-response-with-swagger-and-swashbuckle

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That should be pretty straightforward:

```
[Route("{organizationSys:int}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(List<Door>), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), 400)]
public IHttpActionResult Get(int organizationSys)
```

Note that since you have 2 exit points: one normal return with data, and a catch that returns error message, I've defined in the example above two possible result types:

- http:200(OK) with `List<Door>`
- http:400(BadRequest) with `string`

Swashbuckle Swagger infrastructure will read that and provide **very rough** examples of the data for these cases.

However, if you need **more detailed examples** (i.e. with some reasonable field values) then you will have to implement so-called "example provider". [See here for details and quick tutorial](https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples), in short:

```
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel), typeof(DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeliveryOptionsForAddress(DeliveryOptionsSearchModel search)
```

and

```
public class DeliveryOptionsSearchModelExample : IExamplesProvider
{
  public object GetExamples()
  {
    return new DeliveryOptionsSearchModel
    {
        Lang = "en-GB",
        Currency = "GBP",
        Address = new AddressModel
        {
            Address1 = "1 Gwalior Road",
            Locality = "London",
            Country = "GB",
            PostalCode = "SW15 1NP"
        },
        Items = new[]
        {
            new ItemModel
            {
                ItemId = "ABCD",
                ItemType = ItemType.Product,
                Price = 20,
                Quantity = 1,
                RestrictedCountries = new[] { "US" }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The example provider works in a really simple way: whatever the provider returns, it is serialized to JSON and returned as the example for **given data type**. Just like that.

Now, if your method returned `DeliveryOptionsSearchModel`, the provider would use this data above directly.

Or, if your method returned a larger object, composed of `DeliveryOptionsSearchModel` and few others, then Swagger would use this provider for one part of the response example, and other provider(s) (or default rough examples) for all other parts of the large object.

---

All of the above was for Net Core.

If you use 'normal' Net 4.5/4.6/4.7, then this way is not available, as the Attribute class does not exist. In AspMvc for Net 4.x there's only `[ResponseType(typeof(..))]` attribute that allows to define a single return type. That's OK for most of the times. However, if you really need to differentiate return types over response codes, or if you need to provide good examples, that's a problem.

However! Some good people solved that already. See [this article](https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/). It describes NuGet `Swagger.Examples`, I believe it's for non-core, and it aims at providing better result descriptions.

It defines another attribute - `[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type=typeof(IEnumerable...` to define possible result codes and result types and provides plugin for Swagger to make use of that attribute.

It also provides another attribute, `[SwaggerResponseExample...` that allows you to define the result-example provider, which can provide a custom good example with data, just like IExampleProvider described above for Core. Neat!

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks! Looks like I need to use a namespace for `ProducesResponseType`, but I can figure that out.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm getting 'the type or namespace ProducesResponseType could not be found' despite already having 'using System.Web.Http.Description;'

Comment: @CaseyCrookston - It may be different depending on ASP and Swagger NuGet version.. I currently use net core 2.0, and `ProducesResponseType` resides in `Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60` so not really from Swagger but rather from the AspCore itself.

Comment: Does it exist in 4.6?

Comment: HM.. let me check

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: according to [this one](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/) for non-Core frameworks, it's `[ResponseType(typeof(Foo))]` [see also MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx). However, that's unpretty.. you can't differentiate between different types for different status codes :(

Comment: This works: `[ResponseType(typeof(List<Doors>))]`  Although I'm not seeing a way to specify 200 or 400.

Comment: exactly.  I wish I could do this in Core, but for the server to which this will be deployed, that isn't yet an option

Comment: @CaseyCrookston: see [this article](https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/) It describes NuGet `Swagger.Examples`, I believe it's for non-core, and it's targetted at providing better examples. It defines and uses yet another attribute - `[SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type=typeof(IEnumerable...` to define possible result codes and result types, and `[SwaggerResponseExample...` to define result-example provider. Neat!

Answer (score 14):

For ASP.NET WebApi2 you can use the attributes SwaggerResponse. This you can Specify the status code and the returning type.

```
[SwaggerResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(List<Door>))]
[SwaggerResponse(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Type = typeof(string))]
```

You can find more info here: https://mattfrear.com/2015/04/21/generating-swagger-example-responses-with-swashbuckle/

Comment: This worked for me and the above didn't because I'm on this version, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Core's IOperationFilter does not have schema registry as a parameter in the Apply method Implementation

```
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Comment: @quetzalcoatl , can you please update the example and workaround.